# Associate multiple users to custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, users

Trying to associate multiple users to a custom post type (product) and then display products on user profiles (Buddypress).

Have hit a brick wall trying to decide how best to implement so hoping for suggestions!

I can add custom meta fields but I don't know how I could set this up to display registered users and then select them in the custom post type.

Comment: Have you looked into [user meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) at all?  That would be my first thought.

Comment: yes but haven't managed to make sense of how I might implement. I realised I have already created a taxonomy for each user so I think I'll try to add that taxonomy to the product custom post type and see how that goes.

Comment: Solved this with the Posts 2 Posts plugin :) https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/posts-to-posts